# How to break long lines in Agda

Tags: agda

I need to break this long line:

`postulate flipH/cw/cw/flipH : ∀ (t : Tile) -> flipH (cw (cw (flipH t))) ≡ cw (cw t)`

Agda won't accept any of these:

```
postulate flipH/cw/cw/flipH
  : ∀ (t : Tile) -> flipH (cw (cw (flipH t))) ≡ cw (cw t)

postulate flipH/cw/cw/flipH : ∀ (t : Tile) ->
  flipH (cw (cw (flipH t))) ≡ cw (cw t)
```

but it does accept this which is not very ideal, since it does not give me much space to work with before it gets long again:

```
postulate flipH/cw/cw/flipH : ∀ (t : Tile) ->
                            flipH (cw (cw (flipH t))) ≡ cw (cw t)
```

Is there a way to break line similar to the way we do it in Haskell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`postulate` is a block keyword, meaning that it's set up to parse multiple postulates under a single occurrence of `postulate`. For example:

```
postulate
  A : Set
  B : Set → Set
```

That means you'll have better luck when you put `flipH/cw/cw/flipH` on a new line. For example, you might want to write:

```
postulate
  flipH/cw/cw/flipH : ∀ (t : Tile) ->
    flipH (cw (cw (flipH t))) ≡ cw (cw t)
```